# URL request returning empty list

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I'm using the code below to access the data of an image on my company's website

```
import requests
import time

requ = requests.get('https://modularaspects.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=assetsfullsizephoto36647')
time.sleep(2)
print(requ.text)
```

However it just returns an empty list, whereas if you follow the link you can clearly see data within the 0th index. Any clues?

Please let me know if there's any further information i can provide.

Comment: “*if you follow the link you can clearly see data within the 0th index.*” Can’t reproduce - following the link as suggested yields an empty array `[]` in the response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up with Requests and used Selenium instead. I retrieved the source html and then parsed it with the json library.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import json

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

sel_driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

website_url = 'view-source:https://modularaspects.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2'
imagename = 'assetsfullsizephoto36647'



sel_driver.get(website_url + '/media?search=' + imagename)

output = sel_driver.page_source
output = sel_driver.find_element_by_tag_name('pre').text

parsedjson = json.loads(output)

print(parsedjson[0]['id'])
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check again? I literally copy-pasted your code and it showed me the response data.

Comment: That's very bizarre. Yeah im 100% certain it wouldn't work. It used to work fine then randomly stopped working with no changes to the code...not sure what happened.

Comment: Could it be that you hit your api limit, perhaps you might want to check and set a regular interval that you store your response somewhere to refer to?

Answer (score -1):

What's the response code you're getting? when you try `requ` or `requ.status_code`?

If it isn't 200 it could be an issue with your user-agent and the site is blocking access to the information

If you're able to access the data through your browser, then you can try using the same user-agent with the following:

```
url = 'https://modularaspects.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=assetsfullsizephoto36647'
user_agent = {your user agent here}
requ = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)
```

A quick google search will give you your user agent

Comment: I get back [200] as the response, so it's got access to it

Comment: ```import requests
import time

url = 'https://modularaspects.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=assetsfullsizephoto36647'
user_agent =   {'Content-Type': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0'
}
requ = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)


print(requ.text)
```

still returns an empty list.

Comment: I agree with @NewbieCody I get the full text by copy and pasting your code.